# I am Getting error while building meteor App

Tags: meteor

Build environment

Windows 8: command Shell ( running in admin mode )

Meteor

```
meteor --version
Meteor 1.7.0.3
```

Node

```
node -v
v10.15.1
```

Npm

```
npm -v
5.3.0
```

Erorr while build:

```
W20190205-13:02:24.727(5.5)? (STDERR) D:\murali\new OHIF\Viewers-master\Viewers-
master\OHIFViewer\node_modules\fibers\fibers.js:90
W20190205-13:02:24.771(5.5)? (STDERR)                                   return f
n.apply(this, arguments);
W20190205-13:02:24.771(5.5)? (STDERR)
  ^
W20190205-13:02:24.772(5.5)? (STDERR)
W20190205-13:02:24.772(5.5)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module "fibers/future"
W20190205-13:02:24.772(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.require (D:\murali\new OHIF\
Viewers-master\Viewers-master\OHIFViewer\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boo
t.js:295:24)
W20190205-13:02:24.772(5.5)? (STDERR)     at packages\meteor.js:261:20
W20190205-13:02:24.773(5.5)? (STDERR)     at packages\meteor.js:431:4
W20190205-13:02:24.773(5.5)? (STDERR)     at packages\meteor.js:1578:3
W20190205-13:02:24.773(5.5)? (STDERR)     at D:\murali\new OHIF\Viewers-master\V
iewers-master\OHIFViewer\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:411:36
W20190205-13:02:24.773(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20190205-13:02:24.774(5.5)? (STDERR)     at D:\murali\new OHIF\Viewers-master\V
iewers-master\OHIFViewer\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:220:19
W20190205-13:02:24.775(5.5)? (STDERR)     at D:\murali\new OHIF\Viewers-master\V
iewers-master\OHIFViewer\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:471:5
W20190205-13:02:24.775(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (D:\murali\new OHIF\Vi
ewers-master\Viewers-master\OHIFViewer\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\profi
le.js:510:12)
W20190205-13:02:24.775(5.5)? (STDERR)     at D:\murali\new OHIF\Viewers-master\V
iewers-master\OHIFViewer\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:470:11
=> Exited with code: 1
W20190205-13:02:34.215(5.5)? (STDERR) D:\murali\new OHIF\Viewers-master\Viewers-
master\OHIFViewer\node_modules\fibers\fibers.js:90
W20190205-13:02:34.215(5.5)? (STDERR)      return fn.apply(this, arguments);
------------------
```

Comment: Can you please add the content of `package.json`? Especially around the 1.7 versions there were many issues with the babel dependencies and the build process.